# Differences between POCO and Self Tracking Entities

Tags: entity-framework

I know about POCO and I recently heard about self tracking entities. can any one explain the differences between POCO and STE

Comment: You may find this link useful http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj613924

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self tracking entities are entities which have persistence logic in the getters/setters of the actual entity classes. In short they are entities that understand how to save themselves.

This differs from POCO entities (Plain Old CLR Objects) which are storage only entities (ie they have no internal logic).

The main difference in EF to do with how these are treated is around how EF detects changes. STEs tell EF about the change and EF normally uses a tracking graph to detect changes in attached entites.

**NOTE:** STEs are deprecated in recent versions of EF

There is also a bit of a middle ground between POCO and STEs with EF, called POCO Proxy entities. For this Entity Framework will overload properties of your POCO classes and create a proxy which will tell EF when changes occur. To do this you will need to make all properties on the class virtual. POCO proxies can perform better in certain scenarios, especially when the tracking graph is large. However performance is not better in all cases, see [Arthur Vickers (from EF) post on POCO Proxies](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2011/12/05/should-you-use-entity-framework-change-tracking-proxies/).

Its my understanding that POCO Proxies are intended to replace STEs.